# Use Event Log as a temporary log storage

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, logging, event-log

We're currently designing an organization-wide logging mechanism (based on C#). One of the requirements is to write the log records to a temporary storage, and later move them to a central database, to save performance.

We're currently evaluating two options for the temporary storage - one is an in-memory db, such as SQL CE, and the other is windows's Event Log.
We're not sure if the event log is suitable for this task. We need something that can stand heavy loads (~50 calls a second), easy to read from, and reliable.

What do you think about it? Is the event log a good candidate for these requirements? How does is perform?
Any insight will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Concerning the reliability: Depending on the client settings, the size of the eventlog limits the amounts of entries beeing saved. Since you´re not the only one writing to the eventlog there is a chance that the log might overflow and you´ll loose entries. Have you thought about ETW (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163437.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this is **a** solution but not necessarily the **best** solution, since it really depends on your needs. We have a fixed size file text file that is used as a circular log. We have the benefit of fixed-length log messages so this works for us. Once a day, at a quieter time, a server extracts the log entries it has yet to read. It can handle a couple of hundred entries per second without breaking a sweat. There is a risk that older entries will get overwritten by newer if the server hasn't extracted enough in time, but the size of the file is such that this is unlikely to happen since we also have the benefit of knowing in advance roughly what the maximum number of entries per day will be.

But as I say, it depends on your needs to a large degree as to which solution is best. I haven't used C# event logs but if they're anything like the old Windows NT event loggers, it has the benefit of being able to be read externally without the client program doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). So maybe you can use the same as a central storage too, gaining the same infrastructure for both local and central.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring local log entries to a central database can be a hard job to do. You have to handle all possible exceptions, interruptions etc. For that reason i would suggest considering a solution using SQL Server Compact 4.0 with Microsoft Sync Framework.

I think it is possible to implement a one-way service oriented synchronization solution.

In addition SQL Server Compact 4.0, has a DB size limit of 4GB and handle >250 concurrent connections. Also you have the option to include x86 and x64 bootstrapper packages with your click-once applications.